# Why isn't my DNS pointing to my Digital Ocean droplet server?

Tags: nginx, deployment, dns, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I have my Google Domains DNS configures to point to my Digital Ocean droplet, but my site will not load. I should at least get a notice that my NGINX proxy server is receiving the request, but I'm not. I usually use NameCheap, but I thought Google might be better, and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

[image: HERE> Here you can see that my DNS is pointing to my server with the A record]

[image: HERE> Whatsmydns.net is confirming that my url is pointing to my server.]

However, When I visit my site, the page says that the site can't be reached. [Site is unavailable][3]

Any insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be migrated from my end? Flushed your local dns cache etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain name tannerplauche.com works fine for me. Apparently, it's just propagation time on your end. When you change the DNS, the changes do not take effect instantly. Normally, your local ISP's server updates data every 24-48 hours. Once the cache on the local ISP's server is cleared, you will see the website on your end as well.

In the meantime, you may bypass propagation by checking your domain name via proxy server. Here ist he link: https://kproxy.com/